# Pointer to Structure not working as expected

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Trying to pass reference of structure to a function to input data, but for some reason the program faces run-time problems and crashes. Can someone tell why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int getdata(struct bank *);

struct bank {
char name[40], ac_no[20];
float balance;
};

int main()
{
    struct bank customer[5];
    struct bank *p;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        p = &customer[i];
        getdata(&p);
    }   
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int getdata(struct bank *ptr)
{
    printf("Enter Name: ");
    gets((ptr->name));
    printf("Enter A/C Number: ");
    gets((ptr->ac_no));
    printf("Enter Balance: ");
    scanf("%f",ptr->balance);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: **ptr->balance** crashes the program, can't figure it out :|

Comment: Don't use `gets`, use `fgets` or even `scanf`. As to your problem, if you had used compiler option `-Wall` you would see the problem.

Comment: @Linus: `scanf()` is a very difficult function to use, and also can cause the same overflow problem unless used correctly with a length modifier.

Comment: @iharob yes, I'd definitely use `fgets` over `scanf`, but it is still better than `gets`.

Comment: Compiler warnings do not just exist to show the compiler is working, but to help detect faults in your code. Enable them and pay heed to them! Read the C info page on SO!

Comment: @Olaf can you give me the link to that? I'm new to programming, it would be really generous of you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove the `&` address of operator from `getdata(&p)`. The type of `&p` is `struct bank **p` which means the compiler should have warned about this and you've ignored the warning.

Also, NEVER use `gets()` it's a dangerous function and was deprecated in recent [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) standard.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid. First of all structure `bank` declared as a parameter of the function `getdata` is not the same as the structure `bank` declared after the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int getdata(struct bank *);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
struct bank {  // this is another structure
^^^^^^^^^^^
char name[40], ac_no[20];
float balance;
};
```

Write instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct bank {
char name[40], ac_no[20];
float balance;
};

int getdata(struct bank *);
```

That is place the function declaration after the structure definition.

This call of the function

```
getdata(&p);
```

is also invalid because expression `&p` has type `struct bank **` while the parameter has type `struct bank *`

Write

```
getdata( p );
```

Function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported any more by the C Standard.  Use instead either `fgets` or `scanf` specifying the number of characters to read.

Comment: When I try to input the value for balance through **ptr->balance** at that point the program also crashes. I'm new to C so forgive my petty questions everyone ..